# Install an older version of a package (tmux)

Tags: debian, tmux

Is there a safe way I can install an older version of a package? I'm using Debian 11 and I would like to install the version 2.6 of tmux, because it's the version I'm using in my other computer with Debian 9.

It seems it would be safer to install tmux 2.6 in Debian 11 than tmux 3.1 in Debian 9.

PS. The config file makes them uncompatible.

Edit to post my config file for tmux 2.6, which is not working in tmux 3.1:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Key bindings
#----------------------------------------------------------------

# Change the default prefix binding
unbind-key C-b
set -g prefix C-Space
bind-key Space send-prefix

# Use Zsh as default shell
# Disable it if you don't use Zsh
set-option -g default-shell /bin/zsh

# Limit the scrollback buffer to 10000 lines
set-option -g history-limit 10000

# 256 colors support
set -g default-terminal 'screen-256color'

# Add Ss and Se capabilities for Nvim (see :h tui-cursor-shape)
set -ga terminal-overrides '*:Ss=\E[%p1%d q:Se=\E[ q'

# Enable xterm-keys
set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi

# Enable mouse
set -g mouse on

# Faster command sequences
set -sg escape-time 0

# Window titles
setw -g automatic-rename on
set-option -g set-titles on
set-option -g set-titles-string "#T"

# Start numbering from 1
set-option -g base-index 1
setw -g pane-base-index 1

# Windows navigation (Vim-like)
bind-key -n C-M-h previous-window
bind-key -n C-M-l next-window
bind-key -n C-M-p last-window
bind-key -n C-M-n new-window
bind-key -n C-M-j kill-pane
bind-key -n M-n new-window
bind-key -n M-x kill-pane

bind-key -n M-1 select-window -t 1
bind-key -n M-2 select-window -t 2
bind-key -n M-3 select-window -t 3
bind-key -n M-4 select-window -t 4
bind-key -n M-5 select-window -t 5
bind-key -n M-6 select-window -t 6
bind-key -n M-7 select-window -t 7
bind-key -n M-8 select-window -t 8
bind-key -n M-9 select-window -t 9
bind-key -n M-0 select-window -t 10

# Split window into panes
unbind-key '"'
unbind-key %
bind-key -n M-. split-window -h
bind-key -n M-- split-window -v

# Panes
bind-key -n M-e list-panes
bind-key -n M-t clock-mode

# Panes navigation (Vim-like)
# bind-key -n M-h select-pane -L
# bind-key -n M-l select-pane -R
# bind-key -n M-k select-pane -U
# bind-key -n M-j select-pane -D

# Move between Tmux panes and Vim windows
# - It requires the corresponding configuration into Vim.
# - Check it at my .vimrc, section 9 («Multiple windows»).
# - URL: https://github.com/gerardbm/vimrc/blob/master/vimrc
# - Plugin required: https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator
is_vim="ps -o state= -o comm= -t '#{pane_tty}' \
    | grep -iqE '^[^TXZ ]+ +(\\S+\\/)?g?(view|n?vim?x?)(diff)?$'"
bind-key -n M-h if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys M-h"  "select-pane -L"
bind-key -n M-j if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys M-j"  "select-pane -D"
bind-key -n M-k if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys M-k"  "select-pane -U"
bind-key -n M-l if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys M-l"  "select-pane -R"
bind-key -n M-\ if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys M-\\" "select-pane -l"

# Swap panes (Vim-like)
bind-key -n M-P swap-pane -U
bind-key -n M-N swap-pane -D

# Resize panes (Vim-like)
bind-key -n M-f resize-pane -Z
bind-key -n M-H resize-pane -L 1
bind-key -n M-L resize-pane -R 1
bind-key -n M-K resize-pane -U 1
bind-key -n M-J resize-pane -D 1

# Copy mode (Vim-like)
bind-key -n M-Space copy-mode
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi Escape send-keys -X cancel
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'v' send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'V' send-keys -X select-line
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'y' send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xsel -i -p && xsel -o -p | xsel -i -b"
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'r' send-keys -X rectangle-toggle
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'u' send-keys -X page-up
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'd' send-keys -X page-down
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi Space command-prompt -i -p "search-forward" "send -X search-forward-incremental \"%%%\""

# TODO: toggle function to use only 'ñ'
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'ñ' send-keys -X start-of-line
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'Ñ' send-keys -X end-of-line

# Not using the following (I prefer the clipboard)
# bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'y' send-keys -X copy-selection
# bind-key p paste-buffer

# Reload configuration
bind-key -n C-M-r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display "Tmux settings reloaded!"

# URLview
bind-key -n C-M-o capture-pane \; save-buffer /tmp/tmux-buffer \; new-window -n "urlview" '$SHELL -c "urlview < /tmp/tmux-buffer"'

#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Color Settings
# - The installation of Powerline fonts is highly recommended
# - URL: https://github.com/powerline/fonts
#----------------------------------------------------------------

# Message text
set-option -g message-fg colour3
set-option -g message-bg colour8

# Modes
setw -g mode-fg colour0
setw -g mode-bg colour6
setw -g clock-mode-colour colour6
setw -g clock-mode-style 24

# Panes border
set -g pane-border-bg colour0
set -g pane-border-fg colour7
set -g pane-active-border-bg colour0
set -g pane-active-border-fg colour6

# Panes number
set-option -g display-panes-active-colour colour2
set-option -g display-panes-colour colour6

# Statusbar
set -g status-fg colour6
set -g status-bg colour8
set -g status-left '#[fg=colour0,bg=colour6] s:#S #[default] '
set -g status-right '#[default]  %m-%d #[fg=colour0,bg=colour6] %H:%M '
set -g status-attr none

# Statusbar layout
set -g status-position bottom
set -g status-justify left
set -g status-right-length 50
set -g status-left-length 50

# Statusbar window tab
set-option -gw window-status-fg colour0
set-option -gw window-status-bg colour7
set-option -gw window-status-format "#[fg=colour8,bg=colour7]#[default] #I#{?window_activity_flag,#[fg=colour0]~,:}#[default] #W #[fg=colour7,bg=colour8,nobold]"
set-option -gw window-status-attr none

# Statusbar window tab current
set-option -gw window-status-current-fg colour0
set-option -gw window-status-current-bg colour4
set-option -gw window-status-current-format "#[fg=colour8,bg=colour4]#[default] #I#{?window_active,),} #W #[fg=colour4,bg=colour8]"
set-option -gw window-status-current-attr none

# Statusbar window tab activity
set-option -gw window-status-activity-fg colour0
set-option -gw window-status-activity-bg colour7
set-option -gw window-status-activity-attr none

# ↑ The attributes is either none or a comma-delimited list
# of one or more of: bright (or bold), dim, underscore,
# blink, reverse, hidden, or italics, to turn an attribute
# on, or an attribute prefixed with `no' to turn one off.

# Alerts
set-option -gw monitor-activity on
set-option -g visual-activity off
set-option -g visual-bell off
set-option -g visual-silence on
set-option -g display-time 1500
```

Comment: Could you possibly also show what the incompatible configuration options are? You never know, but it may be possible to create a unified configuration that works on both (but I wouldn't hold my breath).  Also, since the next person is bound to suggest it anyways: One solution would be to upgrade the older system from Debian 9 (the LTS support ended on June 30 2022).

Comment: It would be awesome if I could modify the configuration to have a version for all. I'm gonna post it.